# How to refresh Token on Android

Tags: android, retrofit, token, spotify, okhttp

I have a Google Pixel Phone that has a "Now Playing" features.
I would like to do something like [this](https://ifttt.com/applets/JMSUHaWY-use-pixel-2-s-now-playing-feature-to-add-music-to-a-spotify-playlist) but my own because it fails a lot and duplicate songs.

For beginning I have [this project](https://github.com/jaimeDevelopers/Create-Queen-Playlist), but It is only work for one hour, because the token is done, so i need to refresh it.

So, How i can refresh the token?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use Retrofit 2 with authenticator, when the token is expired the authenticator send request to get/refresh token, and proceed with the current request check this: https://medium.com/knowing-android/headers-interceptors-and-authenticators-with-retrofit-1a00fed0d5eb (go to the authenticator section)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am currently trying [this](https://gist.github.com/CarlosJTorres/057dbf4d8de3095873b15956bdf47935) , something like your link